# Why can’t we use synchronous counters for high clk frequencies?

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, counter, synchronous

My professor said we can’t use synchronous counters for high clock frequencies. Is it because with many flipflops the delay becomes quite big and so the outputs change after the next triggering edge of the clock?

Comment: A more correct statement would be an asynchronous counter will always be faster than a synchronous counter. Whether this is useful depends on the application. There are many applications where a long asynchronous counter would become useless at high frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous counters that cascade edges that are slower (f/2) after each stage and don’t have setup and hold times of sync counters.  Although you’d have to stop the clock and wait for it to ripple thru to read the count, if the prop. Delay exceeded the clock interval.

So pre-scalers used in real-time freq. synthesis are limited to small counts and max frequency must use synchronous counters.